# Multiple request at same time for ml model deployed with node js passing null value

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, express, machine-learning, web-deployment

I have a multiclass text classification model which predicts product and category. I have deployed it in web with node.js. When requested alone, the prediction result is coming back, but when 2 users trying to classify  at same time the output is returning null some error.

Here the code for extracting the input, passing it to the python script and returning the result.

```js
app.post('/send',async (req,res)=>{
  console.log(req.body.text);
  console.log(req.body.subject);
  var final=req.body.subject+req.body.text;
  var options = {
      args:
      [
        JSON.stringify(final)

      ]
    }
    const start = Date.now();
    p.PythonShell.run('output.py', options,   async function(err, results)  {
      var jsonData = results;
      var jsonParsed = JSON.parse(jsonData);
      console.log(jsonParsed);
        res.render('index.ejs',{name:jsonParsed});
        const millis = Date.now() - start;
        console.log(`seconds elapsed = ${(millis / 1000)}`);
      
    });
```

The python script to load models, classify them and returning

```py
new_complaint = json.loads(sys.argv[1])

result_product=ml.predict(fitted_vectorizer.transform([new_complaint]))

result_category=cml.predict(fitted_vectorizer1.transform([new_complaint]))

result_product=str1.join(result_product)
result_category=str1.join(result_category)
finaljson=[]
finaldata={"Product":1,"Category":"test"}
finaldata["Product"]=result_product
finaldata["Category"]=result_category

finaljson.append(finaldata)
jsonstr = json.dumps(finaljson)
print(jsonstr)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide us more details like error tracebacks, to be able to help you with this issue.

Comment: Maybe your node server can only execute one python shell at a time?